# Yii application can be open in webview

Tags: php, cordova, yii

Respected
 i am new to **yii**. Want to know that can we open **yii application** in **webview**(android mobile device), I Have an **Yii Application** and want to open it in **mobile webview**.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The WebView in Android simply displays webpages. It has nothing to do with the server side script, as it will only receive the output from the webserver. Yii is a MVC based PHP framework.